# Need help regarding submitting values through a form with select Box?

Tags: php, javascript

I have a empty select box on a form.

`<select id='essentialDocs[]' ></select>`

through some script i add options to it. Basically it adds URL's. So at runtime html will look
like

```
<select id='essentialDocs[]' >
<option value='http://www.google.com' title='Google'>Google</option> 
<option value='http://www.yahoo.com' title='yahoo'>Yahoo</option>
</select>
```

Now on submitting the form i want to get both of these key:value pairs

like Title:URL   google:http://www.google.com

but on doing `$_POST['essentialDocs']` i only get values and not title's. What modification would help get me both. Also another thing i have on the form is i can switch the ordering of url's on screen. Please suggest some solution

Comment: How do you submit the form, via ajax, or plain old submit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. This may help you..

Just add title in value with : When you submit you get your desire value.

```
<form method="post" action="">
  <select id='essentialDocs[]' name='list'>
    <option value='google:http://www.google.com' title='Google'>Google</option> 
    <option value='yahoo:http://www.yahoo.com' title='yahoo'>Yahoo</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Print post array in PHP

```
<?php 
  print_r($_POST);
?>
```

Output:

```
Array ( [list] => yahoo:http://www.yahoo.com [Submit] => submit )
```

Now you can get both title and URL.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the `title` **map** the `title` to the `URL` **on the server** in e.g A `dictionary` or `array`.

IMHO it would be even better to do it the other way around. Set the title as a value and map it to a URL on the server.

```
  $arr["Google"] ='http://www.google.com'
  $arr["yahoo"] = 'http://www.yahoo.com'
```

then you also have the ability to maintain this array on the server and echo it (back) into the select.

**[more here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)**